# Cherokee and Irish DNA

Tags: dna

I just got my dna results back. Very interesting. But my great-grandmother was 100% Cherokee and her husband was Irish, directly from Ireland. My mother receives a check from the Eastern Band, the family is registered there. It's all very well documented. How is it that neither Cherokee or Irish showed up in my DNA at all?

Comment: What did show up in your DNA results and what test did you use?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is having DNA to compare with. An article on [Access Genealogy](https://www.accessgenealogy.com/native/cherokee-dna.htm) discusses this (emphasis mine):

> First, the readers should understand that if any commercial DNA lab
>   returns tests results that state a percentage of DNA for a particular
>   Southeastern Native American tribe, the report should be considered
>   fraudulent. The American Society of Human Genetics has not certified
>   any DNA test markers to be associated with a particular Southeastern
>   American Indian tribe. 1 The technique for creating indigenous DNA
>   markers is **to sample a statistically reliable number of “ethnically
>   pure” members of a tribe than average their DNA profiles. Since the
>   people who met the first European explorers on the shores of the
>   Atlantic, Gulf and Pacific are genetically not the same people calling
>   themselves Native Americans today, it is a very difficult task.**
>   Virtually, no citizen of a federally recognized Southeastern tribe
>   could maintain their membership, if it was based solely on the DNA
>   profiles of pre-Spanish Conquest individuals.

DNA can't be linked to individual tribes for this reason.